# How should I load all the data from a column to a datagridview combobox?

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcombobox

How can I make that the datagridview combobox loads with the items listed in the 'userid' column in my database? I want all the items to be listed on the datagridview combobox from the 'userid' column.

Here are the lines I've written so far:

```
Private Sub check()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Select UserID from info", con)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "UserID"
        Dim dgvcolumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        With dgvcolumn
            .Width = 150
            .Items.Add(ComboBox1.Items)
            .DataPropertyName = "UserID"
            .HeaderText = "UserID"
        End With
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need `c#` tag for that. `vb.net` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an unbound column, type should be ComboBoxColumn. Then add a data source (named infobindingsource) that grabs the userid column from your info table and set the new column's data source to be the infobindingsource.

ilann